# load page from file and change some content by element's id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a code where I load a file to a DIV:

```
    $(".side-nav a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#page-wrapper").load(file); //file="path to php file"
        $(".title").text(title); //title="some titles"
    });
```

Here is the part of code which I load from file.php:

```
(...)

<h1 class="page-header"> <span class="title"></span><small>details</small></h1>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><a href="#"> Dashboard </a></li>
  <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span class="title"></span> </li>
</ol>

(...)
```

Now I would like to put somehow new title in elements with the `class="title"`. It nothing happens if I do the way like above. How to correct this?

Comment: bcause load is asynchronous.... You basically ordered the pizza and try to eat it as soon as you hit the send button. You need to wait for the pizza to get to your house. Read the documentation for [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following and check if it works

```
 $(".side-nav a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#page-wrapper").load(file,function(){
            $(".title").text(title); //title="some titles"
         }); //file="path to php file"

    });
```

as `$.load` is asynchronous, DOM doesn't wait for `$.load` to execute and try to execute ext statement. at the time it reaches `$(".title").text(,,,)` there is no element present because this entire execution happens in fraction of second or less.

Comment: Thanks, you can find all possible details about $.load here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: actually I knew that the load function is asynchronous, I get also warning in console log "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated...." but this is probably different topic how to replace this whole idea I use for loading pages. I don't know why I couldn't think of this way of solving (I use to do it that way before but not very often). Thank you anyway for guiding me to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

The [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is an ajax short handle which is asynchronous so do it within the complete callback otherwise the element wouldn't be there.

```
$("#page-wrapper").load(file,function(){ 
   $(".title").text(title);
});
```